# Black background on Application screen resize in windows store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm facing black background issue in windows 8.1 store app in the below case.

1. Launch the application.
2. Re-size the app to 40% of the screen
3. On my first screen it has the textbox and keyboard should open when I set focus to that textbox
4. Keyboard is opened in application.
5. Now, Re size application to 50% screen

Here, that addition 5% of screen is occupied with black color.  How could I resolve

ref sample code:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Touch-keyboard-sample-43532fda

Comment: Do you have code to show? What technology are you using, XAML?

Comment: Yes, it is xaml with C#.you can refer this sample.http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Touch-keyboard-sample-43532fda

Answer (score 0):

I got below response from Microsoft blog

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cc6870a6-3238-4b8b-8757-fe16f5adbff1/black-background-on-application-screen-resize-in-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp